# Building and linking shared libraries in an R package - code compiles, links, but won't load

Tags: c++, linux, r, rcpp

Platforms tested: Linux Mint 17, Ubuntu 14.04
Full example: [this repository](https://github.com/grantbrown/RcppCAF).

### What am I doing and why?

I'm trying to build an R package which wraps a subset of the [CAF library](http://www.actor-framework.org/) using [Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp.git) and [RcppEigen](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen.git).

I have successfully linked an R package to a system level install of CAF <strike>([example here](https://github.com/grantbrown/ABSEIR.git))</strike> (Note: ABSEIR no longer uses CAF, 2/5/2015), but I'd like to have a good way to deploy CAF to machines without administrator access, and as a result simplify the installation of other CAF dependent packages (yes, I'm aware that R doesn't directly support linking against other compiled packages, but it seems like others have successfully circumvented this limitation).

### What's the problem?

I'm building two shared objects during package compilation in addition to the package shared object (RcppCAF.so): libcaf_core.so and libcaf_io.so. These are successfully compiled and linked, but the package fails to load, claiming:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/grantbrown/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppCAF/libs/RcppCAF.so':
  librcaf_core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### What have I tried?

In addition to numerous failed Makevars configurations, I've found that
if I manually set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the folder containing the compiled code, the package will successfully install. Obviously, I'd like to avoid this step by finding a way to tell R where to look for these dependencies.  I have attempted to use the *inst* folder for this purpose to no effect. My Makevars file is as follows:

```
ROOT_DIR := $(abspath .)                                                        
$(info The compilation root directory is: $(ROOT_DIR))                          
$(info The name of the shared library to be created is: $(SHLIB))               
$(info The place R should look for librcaf_core.so is: $(abspath ./libcaf_core)) 
$(info The place R should look for librcaf_io.so is: $(abspath ./libcaf_io)) 

SOURCES = $(wildcard ./*.cpp)
SOURCES1 = $(wildcard ./libcaf_core/*.cpp)
SOURCES2 = $(wildcard ./libcaf_io/*.cpp)

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS1 = $(SOURCES1:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS2 = $(SOURCES2:.cpp=.o)

PKG_CPPFLAGS+= -std=c++11 -Dlibcaf_core_shared_EXPORTS -Wall -pedantic -pthread -fPIC -O2 -g -fPIC -I../inst -I../inst/libcaf_core -I../inst/libcaf_io 

PKG_LIBS += -L$(abspath ./libcaf_core) -lrcaf_core -L$(abspath ./libcaf_io) -lrcaf_io

all: $(SHLIB) 

$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) libcaf_core/librcaf_core.so libcaf_io/librcaf_io.so

libcaf_core/librcaf_core.so: $(OBJECTS1)
    g++ -o libcaf_core/librcaf_core.so $(OBJECTS1) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -shared

libcaf_io/librcaf_io.so: $(OBJECTS2) 
    g++ -o libcaf_io/librcaf_io.so $(OBJECTS2) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -shared
```

There are a lot of threads on StackOverflow and mailing lists which deal with problems loading shared objects, but I couldn't find anyone with precisely the same issue. I've even done similar things in the past with no issues, so I'm having trouble figuring out why R can't find my shared objects. Any suggestions?

### Edit

Dirk has suggested compiling to a single shared object, which I'm now working on. In the "Using Makevars" section of "Writing R Extensions", however, it does seems to imply that building dependencies should be possible:

"If you want to create and then link to a library, say using code in a subdirectory, use something like

```
.PHONY: all mylibs

all: $(SHLIB)
$(SHLIB): mylibs

mylibs:
    (cd subdir; make)
```

"

Comment: Why are you building two separate shared libraries?  I think R packages may only work with one but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the structure of the original CAF library, and I've definitely built packages before which successfully link to additional shared objects created during package installation.

Comment: **If** you want to use an external library, use an external library. There are examples for that too -- but it will make things less portable as others then need the external library too.  Else do as Charles suggested and _just let R build it all into one shared library_ which is how packages work.

Comment: Yes, I've successfully gone the external library route, but want to avoid it in this case if possible for the reasons mentioned. I'm also having trouble getting R to link everything when taking your suggestion to compile everything to a single shared object, but am still working on that.

Comment: There are _plenty_ of existing examples.  See for example nloptr where I helped create a 'dual mode': default is download of external library and use.

Comment: I hadn't considered that approach, it seemed like it should be easier to simply use the usual R package compilation infrastructure. I'll give that a shot though, thanks.

Comment: Err, yes, which is what I suggested to you, now multiple times.  Maybe time to leave this venue and ask a real question on rcpp-devel.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood your previous comments or poorly communicated my issues, but I think I have enough to go on for now - if you'd like to submit one of your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

What I hadn't considered was writing a configure script which downloads and compiles an external library as part of the installation process, rather than including the requisite source as part of an R package. My use of the phrase "R package compilation infrastructure" was imprecise and unhelpful, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach, which you also seem to have found as per [your most recent commit](https://github.com/grantbrown/RcppCAF/commit/24a275dcc159ee06447a4ee9e5e37aaeb39256a0) is to just have R 'glue' all object code into a single shared library.

That tends to "just work" but it is a little costly as the library needs to be rebuilt.  We could look into packaging [CAF](http://actor-framework.org/) as an external library which would make [RcppCAF](https://github.com/grantbrown/RcppCAF) more lightweight.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I'd definitely be interested in working on that. Not only would that approach keep RcppCAF smaller, but it might allow the project to keep some of the CAF testing infrastructure and other extensions intact.